# Why every IDE has different keyboard shortcuts for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, debugging, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Every developer knows the **5 basic operations** that IDEs allow to perform during a **debug**:

1. step into
2. step over
3. step return
4. resume
5. terminate

(according to Eclipse vocabulary)

Now take a look to the **keyboard shortcuts** assigned to them, in some IDEs taken as examples:

- Eclipse:

  1. F5
  2. F6
  3. F7
  4. F8
  5. Ctrl+F2
- Borland C++ Builder 5:

  1. F7
  2. F8
  3. Shift+F8
  4. F9
  5. Ctrl+F2
- Visual Studio 2010:

  1. F11
  2. F10
  3. Shift+F11
  4. F5
  5. Shift+F5
- Firefox debugger:

  1. F8
  2. F7
  3. Shift+F8
  4. F6
- Chrome debugger:

  1. F11
  2. F10
  3. Shift+F11
  4. F8

It's a mess... I usually develop with all of them (and more) and I can never remember the correct buttons...

So the question is:

**why these configurations are nowhere near standardized?** Is there a project to standardize them?

**How do you deal with this daily issue?** Changing the configuration for each IDE? In this case which "standard" configuration do you choose?  Many thanks!

Comment: Because they were designed by different groups with different ideas of what *makes sense*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution to this problem I have seen is that some IDEs ship with key-mappings for other IDEs, for example Netbeans has a "Eclipse" preset in its key-mappings options.

The problem with this is the same as OSX using Cmd vs Windows/Linux using Ctrl IMO. Everyone started doing things their own way, and nobody wants to be the one giving up their way, especially since it would piss off their users. Maybe with time most of it will slowly be standardized, with new IDEs adopting standards and old ones dying, but I don't see this happening anytime soon.

Comment: You can actually easily swap keys on OSX. And probably on windows too.

Comment: You can also easily change key bindings in IDEs, the problem is that this is just pushing out the problem towards every individual user, instead of making everyone miserable for a couple weeks once and for all if all IDEs would change to one true standard.

Comment: Yes, they should. You can write a petition, i guess. That'l work)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I have no hope this will ever happen.

Comment: Give me somewhere to sign a petition and I'll sign it....
It gets really annoying when doing web dev, where you're using say Chrome Debugger and Visual Studio debugger at the same time

Comment: Where I can get Netbeans IDE shortcuts preset for Visual Studio >=2013?

Comment: don't defend the undefendable Seldaek, `gdb` doesn't have F keys for stepping. it's `s` `n` etc. The F key is surely a "standard" invented by visual studio and all other IDE has copied the concept, but must have been afraid of copy infringement lawsuits, and/or wanted to express their idiosyncrasy so they made slight variations, but you don't end up with all these IDE choosing F keys by chance.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the hotkeys might be a way to deal with this plague of 21st century.

Comment: at least 2 of the 3 ides you listed allows changing the hotkeys, so you can create a settings file (export for colleagues!) that uses the same keys everywhere...

Comment: @eFloh (and also @letitbe) which IDE do you think can be used as a reference for the others? Maybe Eclipse which seems forward-looking as it's open source and its platform is used for many other applications (e.g. Talend)?

Comment: well, _this_ will really become a flame war. I don't dare to give a first selection, but just to mention, I use visual studio ;)